# CLR multi-dimensioned array traversal performance

Tags: c#, algorithm, multidimensional-array, parallel-processing

In a great many places in the software I write, there are three-dimensioned arrays of `short` or `float`, usually with several million elements. The data is best understood conceptually as a three-dimensioned array, since it describes values at regular locations in space.

I saw a mention elsewhere here that the .NET CLR is not terribly "performant" when it comes to traversing those arrays, for example, when computing new values and populating a second, equally sized and dimensioned array. If this is true, why is that so?

For reasons of readability I've not settled on the idea of using jagged arrays, yet, but if that's really the answer then I'm willing, but:

To get around this it's been proposed to me that I format the data as a single dimensioned array. For example, if my array has dimensions with magnitudes `m`, `n`, and `o`, then I would create a `float[m*n*o]` instead of a `float[m,n,o]`, and write my own indexer to get to the correct array locations during traversal.

The specific use case is in parallelizing the traversal, such as:

```
Parallel.For(0,m)((x) => for(y=0,y<n,y++) { for(z=0,z<o,z++) doSomething(array(x,y,z)); });
```

Where in the single-indexed case there would be a `Parallel.ForEach(myArray, (position) => doSomething(array(Position)))` kind of thing going on instead of the nested `for` loops.

So, the question is, really, would that be any faster than relying on the CLR array indexing that's built in?

**EDIT: I've supplied my own answer below, based on some timing tests. The code is included.**

Comment: You would have to profile it to be sure but I'd bet more of your time is spent copying data then index lookups.

Comment: What's your source for stating that copying a 3D array is slow?

Comment: doSomething() better be a substantial method or the memory bus will defeat attempts at using threading to speed up code.  In which case the array indexing stops being relevant.  You've got several horses, if you want to see which one is fastest then you run them.

Comment: @Servy: He all but shouted it was hearsay; he wants confirmation.

Comment: Remember that float[m,n,o] just like float[m*n*o] risks being larger than 85k which ends up on the Large Object Heap, which can lead to fragmentation. If your arrays are larger than 85kb and you create/destroy them a lot, then consider using float[m][n][o] instead.

Comment: 9 million floats are bound to hit the LOH no matter what I do, but in my case they're reasonably persistent in memory. The app is 64 bit which is how I'm getting around the fragmentation risk. 

@HansPassant, you comment makes me thoughtful. Define "substantial..." doSomething() is a significant calculation performed on all the elements of the array for, for one example, a finite difference time step.

Comment: Another example of DoSomething would be a three-dimensional interpolation of the data as a vector field, or an averaging of a location with some, but not all, of its surrounding values.

Comment: 9M floats in a single array definitely end up on the LOH, but 9M floats in total in e.g. a float[m][n][o] that is roughly cubic in shape consists of many small arrays (each 800 bytes in size). If the data is static in memory it doesn't matter. If I had a lot of churn I'd even consider a hybrid float[m][n*o] to get reasonable large arrays. When traversing multi dimensional arrays do not forget to do it in the direction the cache wants you to do it!

Comment: It is true, and the reason is that the implementation of multidimensional arrays is slow. Even a jagged array, which involves as many bounds checks as an equivalent MD-array but more pointer chasing is actually faster than an MD-array (usually, anyway).

Comment: So much of this could form the basis of a really good answer I could vote up. Why not post your comments as answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran some timings and found that overall performance is that it makes little or no difference:

I used this code below. The timings I got were basically identical in each case:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int ArrayDim1 = 50;
    int ArrayDim23 = 500;
    int ParallelSplit = 50;
    int DoSomethingSize = 100;

    Double sqRoot = 0;

    Single[, ,] multidim = null;
    Single[] singleDim = null;
    Single[][][] jagged = null;

    ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 36 };

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        multidim = new Single[ArrayDim1, ArrayDim23, ArrayDim23];
        for (int x = 0; x < ArrayDim1; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < ArrayDim23; y++)
                for (int z = 0; z < ArrayDim23; z++)
                    multidim[x, y, z] = 1;
        singleDim = new Single[ArrayDim1 * ArrayDim23 * ArrayDim23];
        for (int i = 0; i < singleDim.Length; i++)
            singleDim[i] = 1;

        jagged = new Single[ArrayDim1][][];

        for (int i = 0; i < ArrayDim1; i++)
        {
            jagged[i] = new Single[ArrayDim23][];
            for (int j = 0; j < ArrayDim23; j++)
            {
                jagged[i][j] = new Single[ArrayDim23];
            }
        }

    }

    private void btnGO_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int loopcount = 1;

        DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
        for (int i = 0; i < loopcount; i++)
        {
            TestMultiDimArray(multidim);
        }
        textBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime).TotalMilliseconds.ToString("#,###");

        startTime = DateTime.Now;
        for (int i = 0; i < loopcount; i++)
        {
            TestSingleArrayClean(singleDim);
        }
        textBox2.Text = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime).TotalMilliseconds.ToString("#,###");

        startTime = DateTime.Now;
        for (int i = 0; i < loopcount; i++)
        {
            TestJaggedArray(jagged);
        }
        textBox3.Text = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime).TotalMilliseconds.ToString("#,###");
    }

    public void TestJaggedArray(Single[][][] multi)
    {
        Parallel.For(0, ArrayDim1, po, x =>
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < ArrayDim23; y++)
            {
                for (int z = 0; z < ArrayDim23; z++)
                {
                    DoComplex();
                    multi[x][y][z] = Convert.ToSingle(Math.Sqrt(123412341));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void TestMultiDimArray(Single[, ,] multi)
    {

        Parallel.For(0, ArrayDim1, po, x =>
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < ArrayDim23; y++)
                {
                    for (int z = 0; z < ArrayDim23; z++)
                    {
                        DoComplex();
                        multi[x, y, z] = Convert.ToSingle(Math.Sqrt(123412341));
                    }
                }
            });
    }

    public void TestSingleArrayClean(Single[] single)
    {
        Parallel.For(0, single.Length, po, y =>
            {
                //System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(y.ToString());
                DoComplex();
                single[y] = Convert.ToSingle(Math.Sqrt(123412341));
            });
    }

    public void DoComplex()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < DoSomethingSize; i++)
        {
            sqRoot = Math.Log(101.101);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One huge thing to consider is the order of traversal.  Memory caching is an important part of modern processor performance and cache misses can be (relatively) expensive.  If you index the array across a 'long' dimension that results in crossing cache boundaries, you may cause frequent misses as part of indexing.  As such, the order in which you index is important.  This often means you want to take care in how you choose to order your indices.

Also, when copying, consider that multiple indexing requires computing the 'true' index to the underlying memory block using multiplication/addition.  If you're just copying all elements, though, you could simply increment a single index and access each element without additional computation required.

There are also various condition checks that occur when accessing arrays by index (making the IndexOutOfRangeException possible), which requires more checks when you access via multiple indices.  I believe (though I'm not entirely sure) that the jitter can sometimes optimize single dimensional array access using a simple loop by checking the range only once, rather than on every indexing operation.

Comment: I index in row-major order, traversing the last-order dimension inside loops of the second and then first.

Comment: @Rob Perkins, it may be worth profiling a 3d array vs. a 1d array.  Note that in the 1d case, you can also keep a parallel indexer when you're iterating last-order-first this way and just `i++` on each iteration; this will reduce the number of computations per iteration for the actual array indexing, while still giving you access to x,y,z if you need it.